# NULL Reference Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

When i am trying to access value stored in object it shows null reference error when the value is null.How to check for null values???

```
str = "<html>" + objName.Name + "</html>"
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i tried something like str = "<html>"+ if(objName.name.count>0){objName.name} +"</html>"..but if cannot be used like this

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
if(objName != null)
{
    str = "<html>" + objName.Name + "</html>"
}
```

Comment: Its unclear if they intend to add the <html> even if it doesn't have name value.  I would assume if its and html tag that they would want to include it to be complete if its an html page.

Answer (score 4):

something like:

```
if(objName != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(objName.Name))
{
  str = "<html>" + objName.Name + "</html>"
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for checking all edge conditions.

Comment: there is no need to check null or empty for objName.Name cause if it is null then also it will concate, not give any error due to string.

Comment: yup I was also thinking this, but my defensive programming approach came first :)

Comment: Depends on the situation.  Per the question, this is acceptable, and for future readers, it's helpful to understand why the output might be blank without any exception.

Comment: Thanks..but after using str="<html>"+ objName != null ? objName.Name : string.empty + "</html>" the formatting i did under html tag disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Check null for object like below :

```
str="<html>"+ objName != null ? objName.Name : string.empty + "</html>"
```

Comment: thanks it worked ..but rest of the formatting disappeared ..all the object after first are not showing any values

Comment: can you please specify your problem in details ?

Comment: str=  "<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" + "<div class=Section1>" + "<img img width=100 height=50 id='myImg' src='C:/test.jpg'>" + "<p style='font-weight:bold; color:green;'><u> Test Name </u></p>" + objTest.name.ToString() + "<br/>" +objname.name.ToString() != null ? string.Join(", ", objname.name.ToArray()) : String.Empty + </body> </html> ";

Comment: after applying condition on null object the rest of formatting like image heading everything has disappeared.

Comment: after applying i am getting just objTest.name values ...no image heading anything

Comment: Check objname != null rather than objname.name.ToString() != null

Comment: but i am trying to take different values like objTest.name ,objTest.class etc...

Comment: str= "<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" + "<div class=Section1>" + "<img img width=100 height=50 id='myImg' src='C:/test.jpg'>" + "<p style='font-weight:bold; color:green;'><u> Test Name </u></p>" + objTest != null ? objTest.name : string.empty + "<br/>" + objname != null ? objname.name + objname.class : String.Empty + </body> </html> ";

Comment: even after checking like objName != null i don know where my rest of the formatting disappears..when i remove that part everything comes back like heading  border image

Comment: Give your whole code for str assignment line, so I can find problem

Comment: it exceeds word limit i cant paste here..but its like what i have pasted

Answer (score 0):

Simple case:

`str = "<html>" + (objName != null ? objName.Name : "") + "</html>";`

Little more performant:

```
if (objName == null)
   str = "<html></html>";
else
   String.Concat("<html">, objName.Name, "</html>");
```

If you are doing this a lot, consider using StringBuilder, which might look someting like:

```
var html = new StringBuilder();
html.Append("<html>");
html.Append(objName != null ? objName.Name : "");
...
html.Append("</html>";
```

If you are adding several tags together, and not using StringBuilder you need to do someting like this:

```
str = "<html>" + (objName != null ? objName.Name : "") + "</html>";
str += "<script>" + (objName2 != null ? objName2.Name : "") + "</script>";
```

... where you put a += to concantinate the new part with the last.  Note also that "" is effectively the same as String.Empty.  You might benifit greatly from using "" instead of String.Empty, until you learn to make the code shorter and more readable.

For your code:

`string str;`

```
str = "<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>";
str += "<div class=Section1>";
str += "<img img width=100 height=50 id='myImg' src='C:/test.jpg'>";
str += "<p style='font-weight:bold; color:green;'>";
str += "<u> Test Name </u></p>" + objTest.name.ToString() + "<br/>";
str += objname.name.ToString() != null ? string.Join(", ", objname.name.ToArray()) : String.Empty;
str += "</body> </html> ";
```

... is going to make this much easier to figure out. You shoudl try the StringBuilder aproach which is nearly the same as this. Should make it much easier overall, I promise :)

So specfically here are a few problems:

```
`... + objTest.name.ToString() + ...`
```

This will fail if objTest is null, and makes the

```
`objname.name.ToString() != null`
```

not mean much.

You probably intend to do something like this (for both your objTest and objname):

```
str += "<u> Test Name </u></p>" + (objname != null && objname.name != null ? objname.name.toString() : "") + "<br/>";
```

This protects both objname and objname.name.

Even better would be:

```
string str;
var objNameName = (objname != null) ? objname.name : null;
var objTestName = (objTest != null) ? objTest.name : null;

str = "<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>";
str += "<div class=Section1>";
str += "<img img width=100 height=50 id='myImg' src='C:/test.jpg'>";
str += "<p style='font-weight:bold; color:green;'>";
str += "<u> Test Name </u></p>" + (objTestName != null ? objTestName.ToString() : "") + "<br/>";
str += objNameName != null ? string.Join(", ", objNameName.ToArray()) : "";
str += "</body> </html> ";
```

Comment: Celess after using str="<html>"+ objName != null ? objName.Name : string.empty + "</html>" the formatting i did under html tag disappeared

Comment: I added more.  See how that works for you and maybe helps it all make more sense. This part is hard at first, gets better.